# IntelliJ event.getmessage() and "event" reconized

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

I am following a tutorial on a discord bot and my respond code isn't working At the bottom the event  in event.getAuthor().getName() is red with a error here is my code

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main extends ListenerAdpater {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws LoginException {;

        JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
                String token = "joccjG9PPN1h5F18rwJBNvtZilmhWGH3";
                        builder.setToken(token);
        builder.addEventListeners(new Main());
        builder.build();

        @Override
       public void onMessageReceived (MessageReceivedEvent event)
                System.out.println("We received a message from " +
                        event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
                        event.getMessage().getContentDisplay
        );

        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals ("I am lonely")) {
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Who isn't?").queue();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if you need this but here is my other piece of code

```
group 'BlueBot'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
  compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.0.0_62'
}
```

If you would help me it would be so helpful

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having? Are you seeing an error message? If so, please post the entire message text

Comment: My problem is that my event command at the bottom is not working and I am wondering how to fix it

Comment: Again, please *show the full error message*

Comment: 'the event in event.getAuthor().getName() is red' What do you mean? Is your code being highlighted in red?

Comment: The error code is "Cannot resolve symbol 'event' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code.

1. You misspelled ListenerAdapter class name (ListenerAdpater).
2. You tried to override a supperclass method from within another method (public static void main)
3. Your onMessageReceived was missing curly braces.

   ```
   import net.dv8tion.jda.api.AccountType;
   import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
   import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
   import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

   import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;


   public class Main extends ListenerAdapter {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
           JDABuilder builder = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT);
           String token = "joccjG9PPN1h5F18rwJBNvtZilmhWGH3";
           builder.setToken(token);
           builder.addEventListeners(new Main());
           builder.build();
       }

       @Override
       public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
           System.out.println("We received a message from " +
                   event.getAuthor().getName() + ": " +
                   event.getMessage().getContentDisplay()
           );

           if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("I am lonely")) {
               event.getChannel().sendMessage("Who isn't?").queue();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @JonathanJones You forgot to mark the question as answered